# What type hint should I use to specify a set of functions

Tags: python, python-typing

What type hint should I use to specify a set of functions?
I used to use `Enum` for that, but got into the habit of using the (more convenient to use, in my opinion) `Literal` since python 3.8.

Yet...

This code is accepted by my python (3.10) interpreter:

```py
from typing import Literal
from operator import le, lt, ge, gt

Literal[le, lt, ge, gt]
```

Yet pylance tells me:

```
Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value
```

What's happening here?
Pylance seems to be misaligned with what the python interpreter actually accepts.
Perhaps pylance is just strongly aligned with the `Literal` documentation.

Meanwhile, what should I do? Ignore pylance's lint dictatorship?
Use `Union[le, lt, ge, gt]`? Back to `Enum`?

Comment: `Literal` literally means *literals*: `"foo"`, `1`, `3.14`, etc. It's not an all-purpose enumeration of values. Names bound to functions are not literals.

Comment: You need to bite the bullet and define an enumerated type; `typing` does not provide any tools for defining arbitrary sets of values as a single type.

Comment: "Pylance seems to be misaligned with what the python interpreter actually accepts." - yes, but the Python interpreter itself will accept just about anything. Type hints are almost completely unchecked at runtime. You can write code like `x: 5 = 7` or `x: print('foo') = 'coconuts'` and Python itself won't care.

Comment: Remember, type hinting is strictly optional...

Comment: What it will accept doesn't mean much, because python doesn't enforce type hints. But that's okay. Your IDE and other tools can use them to flag concerns.

Comment: plus one for @chepner's alliteration.

Comment: And `Literal` has really different usage, not equivalent to `Enum` in any way. `Literal` does not provide runtime functionality, after all: it's for simplest cases where you just trust the input and hint for linters (which are not used by most of package users, believe me). It's mostly suitable for internal codebases (with `mypy` or `pyright` enforced in CI) or for really simple cases where you'll raise `ValueError` for incorrect arguments manually. Your case seems to be just a standard `Enum` example. Or just have a `frozenset` of those functions and hint as `Callable` with proper args...

Comment: I'll add another angle: Why would you _want_ to restrict the type of the variable to _only these four_ specific functions in the first place, rather than just allow _any_ function of a compatible **type**, i.e. something like `Callable[[RichCompare, RichCompare], bool]`?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg This is certainly useful - If I was composing a higher-order function that needed to specify, in its first argument, something that does `<` or `<=` comparisons, catching attempts to pass `operator.ge` and `operator.gt` (which has the same signature as `operator.le` and `operator.lt`, even though they do completely opposite things) would certainly be useful. That being said, the traditional way to do this would be through `typing.Literal`s with `enum.Enum`.

Comment: @dROOOze I am not arguing that it is never useful. I am _asking_ OP, why he wants that because maybe in that specific case a broader type would be sufficient (and maybe even beneficial). My comment was merely intended to offer a possible alternative perspective. Often times, I catch myself designing a function for a specific purpose and make the parameter types unnecessarily restrictive just for _that_ purpose. Meanwhile the function would work just as well with broader types and thus could be reusable in other (maybe unforeseen) situations.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg: I agree that it's better to type with the least restrictive type that will ensure the desired behavior (e.g. `Iterable` versus `List`). (In fact, I wish Python made type precision easier to achieve.) Why would I not use just ANY binary Boolean function? Perhaps to align with the usual semantics of those particular operators (transitive/antisymetric relation, total or partial order, etc.). See [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)). But really, it's irrelevant to the question here. My example was just an example.